# How to run AudioQueue in separate CFRunLoopRef

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, cocoa, audioqueue

I need to record and play audio in custom `CFRunLoopRef` object created especially for it.

I created a class for create and start runLoop object.

```
@implementation ThreadUtilities

- (id)init
{
   self = [super init];
   if (self)
   {
      _thread = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(runLoopThreadAccessor) object:nil];
      [_thread start];
   }
   return self;
}

- (void)runLoopThreadAccessor
{
   _runLoop = CFRunLoopGetCurrent();
   if (!_runLoop)
      return;
   NSPort* keepAlive = [NSPort port];
   [keepAlive scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes]; // schedule port for keep runloop alive
   CFRunLoopRun();
}
```

Then I just pass the object while creating `AudioQueue`-object.

```
- (void)startQueue
{
  //...
  m_utilities = [[ThreadUtilities alloc] init]; // m_utilities is a class member
  CFRunLoopRef run_loop = [m_utilities runLoop];
  OSStatus status = AudioQueueNewInput(&m_state.data_format, HandleInputBufferReceived, &m_state, run_loop, kCFRunLoopCommonModes, 0, &m_state.queue);
  //...
}
```

All works fine but time to time my thread crashes with `SIGABRT`-signal while recording/playing. Here's the stack trace

```
4   ???                0x000000011234b028 0x0 + 4600410152
5   libsystem_c.dylib  0x00007fff91d719b3 abort + 129
6   libc++abi.dylib    0x00007fff8f8a3a21 __cxa_bad_cast + 0
7   libc++abi.dylib    0x00007fff8f8cb9d1 _ZL26default_unexpected_handlerv + 0
8   libobjc.A.dylib    0x00007fff948ea7eb _ZL15_objc_terminatev + 124
9   libc++abi.dylib    0x00007fff8f8c90a1 _ZSt11__terminatePFvvE + 8
10  libc++abi.dylib    0x00007fff8f8c8d48 __cxa_rethrow + 99
11  libobjc.A.dylib    0x00007fff948ea5f4 objc_exception_rethrow + 40
12  CoreFoundation     0x00007fff90a71c6b CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 443
13  CoreFoundation     0x00007fff90b29671 CFRunLoopRun + 97
14  MyApp              0x000000010ce9752f [ThreadUtilities runLoopThreadAccessor] + 1905967
```

Should I create runLoop some other way? Or all my idea is a big crap and I should just use `CFRunLoopGetCurrent()` for all of my input/output queues?

Comment: Do I understand correctly that your real issue is that you receive the `SIGABRT` signal in your audio queue thread from time to time?

Comment: @JustSid yes, it crashes inside ThreadUtilities' loop.